# error when installing the glassfish in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, glassfish, web-development-server

when I try to install the glassfish tool in eclipse,it says that the installtion can not be completed because some items required can not be found
the condition is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXife.png)

Comment: Can you share:
1. Eclipse Version,
2. Your OS
so that, I can try it in my VM.

Comment: 1.My eclipse version is Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers - 2019-12 and 2. my operate system is windows 10